# Click on a button from another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one form called Form 1 that has a button click event for button 1.

```
public partial class Form1: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some Code - If a user clicks me button 2 will be executed !
    }
}
```

I have another form in other aspx page called Form 2 with the button button2.

```
public partial class Form2: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some Code
    }
}
```

So far so good,
My question is how can i do, if a user click the button1 in Form1, button2 in Form 2
will be fired ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You should move that code to a static function in a common class, then call that function from both handlers.

If you're reference controls on the other page, the whole question makes no sense.

Comment: I am new with this so it will be helpful if you could give me an example in code, thanks.

Comment: @GiladAdar: Are you asking how to create a class?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery you can do this:

```
$('#Button1').on('click', function () {
    $('#Button2').click();
});
```

However, I would question why you cannot do this by sharing code instead.

Comment: `I have another form in other aspx page called Form 2 with the button button2`, he states that button1 and button2 are in different pages